# Centering input box in form

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I want to make input box stays at center of a form, but I cannot make it work even using `margin: 0 auto;` or `display: inline-block;`

```
#message {
    width: 90%;
    ...
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sma9x76v/)

Comment: Add `#message{text-align: center;}`

Comment: `display: block` should help.

Answer (score 3):

`margin: 0 auto` works only with `block` elements, so :

```
#message {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sma9x76v/1/)

Comment: oooh I see. Understood now

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple way:

```
<form id="subform" autocomplete="off" style="text-align:center">
<input id="message" placeholder="message goes here" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:center` to `#subform`

`Input` acts as `inline-block` element which you can simply `align` by giving `text-align` property to parent

```css
#subform {
  text-align: center;
}
#message {
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 25px;
  line-height: 27px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #333;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #C0C0C0 #D9D9D9 #D9D9D9;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  border-image: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<form id="subform" autocomplete="off">
  <input id="message" placeholder="message goes here" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way -

```
<input type="text" style="text-align:center;" >
```